# word-wrap:break-word - don't break strings

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to show in my view list of all comments from database. But sometimes, comments ale very long. I tried to "break" them with `word-wrap:break-word`, but with no result - comments like this

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

extend my view..

and I want to show:

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

How to do it? CSS `Width` property also don't work.

Here is my code:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
@foreach (var comment in Model.commentList)
{ 
    <tr style="border-bottom:1pt solid black;">
        <td style="width: 30%;">
            <br />

            @comment.UserName<br /><br />
            @comment.AddDate
            
        </td>
        <td style="word-wrap:break-word; width: 70%;">
            <br />
            @comment.Content
            
        </td>

    </tr>
    

}

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `word-wrap: break-word` doesn't seem to work normally in tables. There is a fix for it though. Try the following code (note the additional `table-layout: fixed` in the `table` tag).

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
@foreach (var comment in Model.commentList)
{ 
    <tr style="border-bottom:1pt solid black;">
        <td style="width: 30%;">
            <br />
            @comment.UserName<br /><br />
            @comment.AddDate
        </td>
        <td style="word-wrap:break-word; width: 70%;">
            <br />
            @comment.Content
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```